# Please recommend opensource automation tool for windows form based application testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, windows-7, automation

I am looking for an open source tool for doing automation testing of my windows form application in windows 7.

Comment: Need something like selenium, that interacts with running application GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I use http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/ NUnitForms. It's an extension of the venerable NUnit framework and supports Visual Studio. There are lots of plugins for Visual Studio that can help with managing your tests. I use JetBrains Resharper http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ to do the trick. You can also just use the built in functionality and run the tests from NUnit itself.

Hope this helps,

Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Answer (score 0):

If you need GUI testing, hook up unto gui manually and create your own 'clickers' and 'inputers' for it.  Keep it as simple as possible, to avoid producing bugs in that code.  Then, you can call this from Nunit.